# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, express, cors, xmlhttprequest

Exact error message: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7000/profile/picture?url=me' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I'm using express version 4.16.4. In my application, after I upload an image and logout, I get this error when I log back in. I added the following to my main server:

```
app.use('*', cors({ 
        credentials: true, 
        origin: true, 
        methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS', 
        preflightContinue: true
    }));

... (routes here)

app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
        origin = req.get('origin');

        // Development whitelist
        var whitelist = ['http://localhost:8080', 'http://localhost:8081'];

        corsOptions = {
            origin: function (origin, callback) {
                    var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
                    callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
            }
        };

        next();
    });
```

I get `OPTIONS` logs, but none of the routes are hit. Also no error messages are thrown in Node.

Comment: Why is `preflightContinue` true? What is the .all that follows for? it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @KevinB I was trying to restrict the node app to only communicating with my vue app.

Comment: For it to work at all, it would need to come *before* the routes, otherwise it might not be ran at all. But the code you have within it doesn't actually do anything. You define three variables that contain either objects or strings, and then... call next(). You could use such a function in place of your first one to only allow CORS to your whitelist, but you shouldn't use both. The first one should be enough to allow CORS requests, assuming you correctly detect OPTIONS requests at some point and respond with 200 or change preflightContinue to false.

Comment: I'm getting this error now:
`...has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Comment: Yup, can't use "true" for the origin option for credentialed requests. You need to replace it with a callback that returns an origin value. (this is where the whitelisting happens) https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Answer (score -3):

Try this way:

```
const whitelist = [
  'http://localhost:8080',
  'http://localhost:8081'
];

const corsOptions =  (origin) => {
    return whitelist.some(wl=> wl.localeCompare(origin) === 0);
};

app.use( (req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    if(!corsOptions(req.headers.origin)){
      const error = {
        erro : "This aren't a public API."
      };
      res.sendStatus(500).json(error);
      next();
    }
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
```